# How to display AVX registers as doubles with GDB?

Tags: gdb, simd, sse, cpu-registers, avx

I was trying to use AVX in a Mandelbrot program and it's not working right.

I try debugging it but GDB refuses to show me the floating point values in the YMM registers.    Here's the minimum example

t.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void loadnum(void);
extern double input[4];
extern double output[4];

int main(void)
{
       /*
       input[0] = 1.1;
       input[1] = 2.2;
       input[2] = 3.3;
       input[3] = 3.14159;
       */
       
       printf("%f %f %f %f\n",input[0],input[1],input[2],input[3]);
       
       loadnum();
       
       printf("%f %f %f %f\n",output[0],output[1],output[2],output[3]);
       
       return 0;
}
```

l.asm

```
 section .data

global input
global output

 align 64
input   dq 1.1,2.2,3.3,3.14159
output  dq 0,0,0,0

 section .text

global loadnum

loadnum:
        vmovapd  ymm0, [input]
        vmovapd  [output],ymm0
        
        ret
```

how it's compiled

```
OBJECTS = t.o l.o
CFLAGS = -c -O2 -g -no-pie -mavx -Wall

t:  $(OBJECTS)
    gcc -g -no-pie $(OBJECTS) -o t

t.o:    t.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) t.c

l.o:    l.asm
    nasm -felf64 -gdwarf l.asm
```

The output is

```
> 1.100000 2.200000 3.300000 3.141590
> 1.100000 2.200000 3.300000 3.141590
```

which shows it's loading and storing these doubles as expected, but in gdb it shows

```
> gdb t (followed by some boilerplate)
> Reading symbols from t...
> (gdb) b loadnum
> Breakpoint 1 at 0x4011b0: file l.asm, line 15.
> (gdb) run
> Starting program: /somedir/t 
> 1.100000 2.200000 3.300000 3.141590

> Breakpoint 1, loadnum () at l.asm:15
> 15            vmovapd  ymm0, [input]
> (gdb) n
> 16            vmovapd  [output],ymm0
> (gdb)
```

then I say

```
> (gdb) info all-registers
```

and this shows up.

```
> ymm0 (blah blah) v4_double = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x3}
```

when I expected it to show

```
> ymm0 (blah blah) v4_double = {1.100000 2.200000 3.300000 3.141590}
None of the other fields show anything like that, unless you want to parse the floating point bits
> v4_int64 = {0x3ff199999999999a, 0x400199999999999a, 0x400a666666666666, 0x400921f9f01b866e}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `p $ymm0.v4_double` defaults to decimal formatting.  Use `p /whatever` for other formats.  (`display $ymm0.v4_double` can work as a stand-in for `layout reg vec` being buggy/broken in some versions, and always an unusable mess of different formats.)

Comment: Thanks, "display $ymm0.v4_double" worked beautifully! Now if you'd put that in an answer I could accept it.

Comment: Since I posted this, I had a problem with loading vars and showing weird results in gdb, changing the "align 32" to "align 64" fixed it if anybody tries assembling that code. Edited the original while I was at it.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference for correct code and correct usage of GDB.  (Unless there are GDB bugs).  The unusual things about your original code were that it doesn't use RIP-relative addressing for static data (`default rel`), and that the source and destination were both in `.data`, vs. copying from `.rodata` to `.bss`.  Although that's plausible for a real use-case where other code not shown here might modify the source data, and maybe you want the destination in the same cache line if that's better for performance in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p $ymm0.v4_double` (the `print` command) defaults to decimal formatting.

Use `p /whatever` for other formats, like `p /x $ymm0.v4_int64` to see hex for the bit-patterns.  `help p` for more.

---

`display $ymm0.v4_double` can work as a stand-in for `layout reg` + `tui reg vec` being buggy/broken in some versions, and always an unusable mess of different formats for registers as wide and numerous as ymm0-15.  It takes the same options as `p`rint, and prints before every prompt.  (`undisplay 1` or `undisplay` (all) to disable some of the expressions you've set up.)

It can get cluttered in TUI mode (`layout asm` or `layout reg` + `layout next` to see integer regs and disassembly) if you want to track more than a couple registers, so you might prefer to use non-TUI mode, either don't use `layout` in the first place, or `tui dis`.

(When debugging hand-written asm, I almost always want to look at disassembly, not source; but maybe for a complicated algorithm I'd sometimes want to see source with comments as a reminder of what the values should be/mean at a certain point.)